# Safari Webapp force to open Safari when click another link

Tags: html, ios, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am working with Safari web app for iDevice. I got the configuration right from [Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) and it went well without any issues. In my web app, there is a link for logging out the web page that requires to redirecting the webpage. The problem is when it redirects, it opens Safari app instead of redirecting in the web app. It's not like Google Chrome on Android device, it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using javascript to redirecting instead of using a tag.